# Unable to Record in Apache JMeter in Chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, jmeter, ssl-certificate, recording, certificate-error

I am trying to record a user flow in chrome browser but I am getting the following error:

[image]

Although I have added a recently generated Certificate before recording and I am able to record the flow in Firefox.
Here in chrome, I am getting exceptions that:
(I tried by clicking on Advanced --> proceed but the same message comes again)
[image]

This is my chrome setting:
[image]

JMeter Setting:
[image]

Any solutions for this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install JMeter's certificate in Chrome, see:

- [Manage Certificates](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/topic/6330253?hl=en&ref_topic=9028497)
- [How do I manually install the Securly SSL certificate in Chrome?](https://support.securly.com/hc/en-us/articles/206081828-How-to-manually-install-the-Securly-SSL-certificate-in-Chrome)
- JMeter documentation on [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

> **Installing the certificate in Chrome or Internet Explorer**
>
> Both Chrome and Internet Explorer use the same trust store for certificates.
>
> - Browse to the JMeter launch directory, and click on the file ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt, and open it
> - Click on the "Details" tab and check that the certificate details agree with the ones displayed by the JMeter Test Script Recorder
> - If OK, go back to the "General" tab, and click on "Install Certificate …" and follow the Wizard prompts

Also be aware that there is easier way of recording a JMeter test using Chrome - [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium), in this case you won't have to worry about proxies and certificates

Comment: Yes, I have added that JMeter certificate. But it's very slow and random errors are coming(above mentioned also).
I have used the extension as well. I asked the above question from a learning point!